# How to write a "SQL generator" for EF core

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-6.0

I'm working on a C#, dotnet 6, EF core application that uses MSSQL server as storage. I would like to convert an existing DateTimeOffset column (datetimeoffset(7)) to DateOnly (date).

I'm encountering a problem in a few queries that that extracts the year and month from the content of that column: `The LINQ expression xxxx could not be translated.`

I have narrowed it down to the use of DateOnly.Month or DateOnly.Year in the group by clause of the queries. Here is a short test that illustrate that problem:

```
// The "Entry" entity can be defined as this:

    [Table("Entries")]
    public class Entry
    {
        //...
        [Required]
        public DateOnly BookingDate { get; set; }
        //...
    }
```

```cs
        [Fact]
        public async Task TestDateOnly()
        {
            using var context = CreateContext();
            var res = (from entry in context.DbContext.Set<Entry>()
                group entry by new { entry.BookingDate.Year, entry.BookingDate.Month, entry }
                into gr
                select new { gr.Key.Year, gr.Key.Month });
            var _ = await res.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

This causes the following exception:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Entry>()
    .GroupBy(e => new { 
        Year = e.BookingDate.Year, 
        Month = e.BookingDate.Month, 
        entry = e
     })' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.
```

The issue does not occures when the data type of the BookingDate column is DateTime or DateTimeOffset.

It seems to me that I need to find a way to let the SQL provider for EF core know how to translate ".Year" and ".Month" to SQL when the type the method is applied to is DateOnly.

How should I go about solving this?

***Edit***

It seems that I didn't describe my problem clearly enough.

I do NOT have any issue with reading or writing entity properties of type DateOnly to the database's "date" columns nore do I have any problem with the change tracker capability of detecting change.

My problem is that the DateOnly type has extension methodes (.Month and .Year, specifically) that are not translated by the SQL server EF core provider. These methodes have been defined for the DateTime/DateTimeOffset CLR types but no amount of conversion/cast will help with Linq queries (since these translate the expression themselves)

Since I posted this question, I have found someone having a similar issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28111

Unfortunately, I have been unsucessful in actually finalizing that code.

**Edit 2**

It seems these methodes have not been implemented in EF core 7 either :(

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping

Comment: Have you tried `cast` or `convert` in your sql query on the DateTimeOffSet columns?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm afraid that isn't really helping... Trying to define a custom function fails because EF core fails to understand that the date SQL type and the DateOnly CLR type are compatible. I can therefore not provide the proper parameter there

Comment: @ProdigalTechie I am afraid you have misread my question: converting the column in the migration isn't my issue. my issue is that it seems that EF core 6 (by default) doesn't have a translation for the Month and Year methods of DateOny (even if they are the same as for DateTime)

Comment: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2022/01/07/dateonly-and-timeonly-support-with-entity-framework-core-6-0/

Comment: @SteveFord Thank you but, once more, that post is NOT about the problem I am describing here